# ArcGIS Pro crashes when importing photogrammetric multipatch?

Tags: import, arcgis-pro, photogrammetry, multipatch, collada

I am new to the ArcGIS platform, so please bear with me.

I have run some tests on both ArcScene and ArcGIS Pro before my jobs decides with program to buy.

ArcScene imports 3d models exported from Agisoft Photoscan without a lot of hassle. Although to import a georeferenced model, I had to export two Collada models from Agisoft Photoscan Pro: one in a local coordinate system, and one in a global coordinate system.

In ArcScene I first imported the "global" one which looks like Lego blocks (I have no idea why), but then replaces the multipatch with the "local" one, and it works in ArcScene.

However, when trying this work-around in ArcGIS Pro, the program stalls and crashes.

Am I doing something wrong, or is it a fault in the program?

Comment: I have voted to close this as non-reproducible because no one has indicated either way whether they have enough information to test.  If doing this is important to you then I recommend trying to work through it with your local Esri support, who should be keen to remove any stumbling blocks to a potential sale.